# How to narrow a type among several derived class instances while processing an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to narrow down a type inside a `.forEach` loop (last statement in the below snippet).

In that loop, TS thinks that `obj` is `ObjA | ObjB` (because TS simply made a union of all possible values for that key in the array) and the method needs `ObjA & ObjB` (because TS made a list of possible arguments and made intersection out of them) which are obviously not the same.

However, the code is obviously correct (because the array elements' `obj` and `cls` keys are matched and can be used together):

```
type ObjBase = { id: string };

abstract class Base<T extends ObjBase> {
  abstract processObj(obj: T): string;

  useObj(obj: T) {
    return this.processObj(obj);
  }
}

// Module A
type ObjA = { someKey: string } & ObjBase;

class DerivedA extends Base<ObjA> {
  processObj(obj: ObjA): string {
      return obj.id + obj.someKey;
  }
}
// ========

// Module B
type ObjB = { otherKey: string } & ObjBase;

class DerivedB extends Base<ObjB> {
  processObj(obj: ObjB): string {
      return obj.id + obj.otherKey;
  }
}
// ========

const modules = [
  { obj: { id: 'a', someKey: '' } as ObjA, cls: new DerivedA() },
  { obj: { id: 'b', otherKey: '' } as ObjB, cls: new DerivedB() },
] as const;

modules.forEach(module => {
  module.cls.processObj(module.obj);
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

**How do I fix the error inside that `.forEach` and make TS understand that it's safe?**

The intent behind all this is to have several 'modules' in the application that re-use a lot of code (represented here by `Base#useObj` and insides of `forEach` loop). **Maybe I need to use some other, better structure of my things that I'm just not seeing here?**

*Note that I do not want to refer to each individual module entities inside that loop as it would defeat the purpose of making them conform to one interface.*

Comment: You want a *heterogeneous array* and assuming you can't or don't want to store a hardcoded mapping anywhere like `{a: ObjA, b: ObjB, ...}` the compiler can use to correlate things as per [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), then the ideal solution would be [*existential generic types*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), but those aren't directly supported. You can emulate them with `Promise`-like indirection, as shown [in this playground](//tsplay.dev/WJBDZW). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm fine defining those mappings at the time of module definition (`const modules = ...`) but I don't want any explicit specific module references at the time of usage (`.forEach` insides). I am examining this GH issue you linked and it seems to fit my requirements (although makes my brain hurt a bit so can't confirm yet) so you may already have helped me :) I will update once I'm sure either way.

Comment: If you're okay storing that mapping somewhere then ms/TS#47109 gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjlx2m).  Let me know when you know which way, if any, you'd like an answer to go.

Comment: @jcalz I've started exploring this strategy further and got stuck again [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wkzrjm). Basically it's the same but we try to 'determine module for item processing' (we moved `obj` from module array to `items` array). I can't seem to make it select the appropriate constructor. On line 64 it knows that `module` is `modules[K]` (and not `module-a | module-b`) but it still fails on line 67 (after it wrongly reverts to `cls` being `DerivedA | DerivedB` and not `ClassMapping[K]` as `Module` says).

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvzLYW) is how I would do it. I'm not sure how much further afield I'm willing to travel with you from the question as asked. How should we proceed here? I can write up an answer to the above and you can run with it or ask a new question if you hit a roadblock, or you could [edit] this question to reflect an expanded/different scope (but I can't guarantee I'd follow along).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you! Yes you can write the answer for the question as is based on TS#47109 and I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `modules` is supposed to be a *heterogeneous array*, where instead of each element being some fixed `Module` type, each element is of a different [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, like `[GenericModule<Obj1>, GenericModule<Obj2>, ⋯]`, where `GenericModule<T>` is

```
interface GenericModule<T extends ObjBase> {
  obj: T,
  cls: Base<T>
}
```

And inside of your [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop you really just want to deal with `GenericModule<T>` for *some* `T` you don't care about.  This is one of the canonical use cases for what's known as [*existentially quantified generic types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) (like "for each element of `modules` *there exists* some `T` such that the element is of type `GenericModule<T>`).  But like most other languages with generics, TypeScript does not directly support existential generics.  (Although there is a longstanding open feature request for them at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).) So you need a different approach.

There are different approaches you can take:

---

If you have some fixed known set of `T`s you want to support, you can replace existential generics with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  (Existential generics can be thought of as "infinite unions", while regular generics, or "universal" generics, can be thought of as "infinite [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).)  But inside `forEach()`, TypeScript will fail to see it as safe.  Even though the union `GenericModule<Obj1> | GenericModule<Obj2>` should allow you to safely write `module.cls.processObj(module.obj)`, the compiler complains. It cannot see the *correlation* between `module.cls` and `module.obj`. Instead, `module.cls.processObj` becomes a union of functions, and you can only safely call those with an intersection of arguments (see [the release notes for TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)), and you get an error about `ObjA & ObjB`.

This issue with correlated unions is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The recommended/supported approach to this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring away from unions to a special form using a "basic" mapping interface where you give a key to each element of your union, like

```
interface Mapping {
  a: ObjA,
  b: ObjB
}
```

And then all your operations are written in terms of that interface, or in terms of generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that interface, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.   Like this:

```
type Module<K extends keyof Mapping = keyof Mapping> =
  { [P in K]: GenericModule<Mapping[P]> }[K]

const modules: Module[] = [
  { obj: { id: 'a', someKey: '' } as ObjA, cls: new DerivedA() },
  { obj: { id: 'b', otherKey: '' } as ObjB, cls: new DerivedB() },
] as const;

modules.forEach(<K extends keyof Mapping>({ obj, cls }: Module<K>) => {
  cls.processObj(obj); // okay
});
```

The `Module<K>` type takes a generic type argument for `K` which is some subset of `keyof Mapping`.  `Module<"a">` is equivalent to `GenericModule<ObjA>`, and `Module<"b">` is equivalent to `GenericModule<ObjB>`, and just `Module` is the same as the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `Module<"a" | "b">` which is equivalent to the union `GenericModule<ObjA> | GenericModule<B>`.  So `modules` is of type `Module[]`.

And now the `forEach()` callback is generic and accepts a `Module<K>`.  And this works, because the type of `cls.process` is seen as the single generic function type `(obj: Mapping[K]) => string` while `obj` is seen as `Mapping[K]`. No unions involved anymore, just a single generic function type being called with the expected argument type.

---

Another approach, if you don't have a fixed list of types to support or you don't want to assign keys to these types, is to just emulate existential generics by converting them to a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-like structure.  Consuming an existential generic is equivalent to providing a universal generic and vice versa. This is described inside microsoft/TypeScript#14466 at [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#issuecomment-1287179795).

Given `GenericModule<T>`, we can define `Module`, the existential version, like this:

```
type Module = <R>(cb: <T extends ObjBase>(module: GenericModule<T>) => R) => R;
```

So a `Module` is like an already-resolved promise for a `GenericModule<T>` where you don't know `T`.  All you can do is give it a `then`-like callback which returns something whose type you *do* know.  For any regular `GenericModule` you can wrap it to make a `Module`:

```
const someModule = <T extends ObjBase>(module: GenericModule<T>): Module => cb => cb(module);
```

And then your `modules` array can be rewrapped:

```
const someModules: Module[] =
  [someModule(modules[0]), someModule(modules[1])];
```

And now you can process them by giving each of them a callback:

```
someModules.forEach(m => m(({ obj, cls }) => {
  cls.processObj(obj); // okay
}));
```

---

Each of these approaches preserves some level of type safety, and each has benefits and drawbacks, and neither one is without some effort and complexity.  Which one, if any, is acceptable for a particular task depends on the use case and requirements.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-wwwDCWAtFQMES9IOgqk1iQeDGCQu9gKPahyE8PQz2vZItTDABRXg4hsOsGytKAez7NdO0HGwUMQUjRAYUgVz2XpNGCTA7VCV0Ug5dILgQHJy30wpfX9QN024uREi2YB8BQQRuK6aoUGshMHiYk92IRURsAfYVpN5NCSAwz9v3+P9BgIoDrQQWpZPAiAoMWGD1loxDHz80gAvfLDvxlXC5Xwt9CP0KKkFiqAKMSqiaRS+jioEY9gFYqBYQgBzI2geRLKUazbKgWhDSoHgvCrK8EQxCQACVNBsHgSygc06W2YlbRsDyagXAb8GNc89ikFS2m0CbVMOprYSY1YKH4LUzC6fQRQgWhHIoWJTH0GJOvIbqbMEF0Gp-HpFPGmRFoZNEVrWiANqXQbFM9G5AbUgQ4AOpHVp2-S9C8M6Ewu-gIdEYBXpQGIUHDFAQFedsPqs760F+5j+FCxTL0U282kfMcmZ2tGOLHAAGWcnBC39FJ5zyxwARkF2dTtKU50gtLrqB6sivC5jiki4iheJ4fjbsRrobCkn4EFkxhjoePRYRoKA8ogHLEAIUQ+2Jt6ExAM9fD6zaeFiFEoGBy0lrBjBv2JwgBDIp3Kb9poPT24XYgSUQILDJs3UfTT5fOTIAgx839IKIA)