How can I use TypeScript's type system to prevent object keys from being used in the wrong objects in a nested data structure?
I have a data structure which uses deeply-nested keys to access its properties. I've created a minimal example and added comments to explain how it works. Understanding this data structure is critical for understanding the question I am asking, so please pay attention to the comments I have added.
// Overall data
const fruits = {
  // There are broad categories which contain many items
  alfa: {
    contents: {
      // One such item in the 'alfa' category is 'apple'
      apple: {
        // Each item has associations with other items
        associations: {
          // 'apple' is associated with 'orange' from the 'oscar' category
          oscar: ['orange'],
          // and with 'grape' and 'grapefruit' from the 'golf' category
          golf: ['grape', 'grapefruit'],
          // If a category key is not included, that means this item is not
          // associated with any data in that category
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // Here is another category -- notice that keys from each 'associations'
  // object map to keys in the overall data
  golf: {
    contents: {
      grape: {
        associations: {
          // Also notice that items within the array are all keys within the
          // contents object of the listed category
          golf: ['grapefruit'],
        },
      },
      grapefruit: {
        associations: {
          alfa: ['apple'],
          golf: ['grape'],
        },
      }
    },
  },
  oscar: {
    contents: {
      orange: {
        // The orange item isn't associated with any data
        associations: {}
      }
    }
  }
};

As can be seen, many values within the data structure must refer to values in other parts of the data structure. I want to add type annotations which use this fact to add additional safety to my type checking. I believe that I'll need to use some form of generics to accomplish this, but I am not sure what I need to do specifically.
Here is an example of the kinds of errors I want to catch.
const apple = fruits.alfa.contents.apple;

for (const association of apple.associations.golf) {
  // association should have a type like Association<'golf'>
  const associatedData = fruits.alfa.contents[association];
  //                            ~~~~          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  // Currently, TypeScript gives an error here because the data is hard-coded,
  // but without hard-coded data it would not know there is a problem.
  // I want TypeScript to use the type of `association` to recognise that it
  // cannot be used to access contents within `fruits.alfa` as it is an
  // association from the `golf` category.
  console.log(associatedData);
}

// However in this case, it should not produce an error because `association`
// has a type like Association<'golf'>`, and so accessing items in the contents
// of `fruits.golf` is safe.
for (const association of apple.associations.golf) {
  const associatedData = fruits.golf.contents[association];
  console.log(associatedData);
}

I've tried my hand at writing a solution, but I am not sure how to continue with it:
type ItemName <CategoryName> = string & { __cat: CategoryName };

type Item<CategoryName extends string> = {
  name: ItemName<CategoryName>,
  //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // Name of item belonging to the given category
  description: string
  associations: Record<string, ItemName<'???'>>
  //                   ^^^^^^           ^^^^^
  // I don't know what to put in either of these spots
}

type Category<CategoryName extends string> = {
  name: CategoryName
  description: string
  contents: Record<ItemName<CategoryName>, Item<CategoryName>>,
}

Is there a way that I can accomplish this using TypeScript? If so, how? If not, why not?

Please [edit] to provide an actual [mre]. Right now this isn't complete because your fruits example misses things apparently required, like the existence of the oscar key (writing "etc" isn't helpful for my IDE). It's not clear to me whether associations is supposed to include every other category, or if can omit some, since the example isn't complete, I can't tell whether omissions indicate brevity or optionality. It's also not minimal, since we really don't care about things like description. Even name is unnecessary since it's presumably the same as the key, right?

(See prev comment). Even if you do come up with a generic type, it's not clear that it will do much for your for loop above, since that requires a sort of genericness that becomes difficult to write. I could almost imagine writing the code at this playground link but I don't know if it meets your needs. Hopefully you [edit] to clarify based on the first comment and let me know if this approach here is reasonable for you.

@jcalz thanks for the feedback. I have edited the example to make it complete, and removed the extra data (it was there because I've had people suggest using simpler data structures on other questions, because leaving out that information made the question seem simpler than it was). To clarify, associations are optional, and not including a category means that there is no associated data in that key -- it's essentially a "see also", which I'll use to link between pages in a wiki-like website.

In reality, the information will be loaded from the file system, so I don't think there's much point in extracting the keys of the data (since I wouldn't get editor support for specific values anyway). The main thing I want is to make it so that I can't use the name of an item in one category to attempt to access an item in another category.

I'm not sure how such a mistake would be allowed unless you're using string index signatures, but I don't see you doing that anywhere. My approach here would still look like this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Your solution looks pretty solid, and works for the simple case I have written, but would it continue to work if TypeScript can't statically analyse the data (ie it doesn't know that the categories are alfa, golf, etc, and doesn't know any of the items within them)? I don't need intellisense for them, I just want certainty that I'm not mangling categories with each other. Additionally, I might add the name properties back, since I want the data to have a reference to its own identity (useful to avoid passing them around as extra data).

Without being able to see the use case as a [mre] it's hard for me to say. If TS doesn't need to statically know the cases, then a generic function (like foo) should be fine, but if you are loading the data from the file system, then there's no great specific type to give it. You want it to be declare function loadFruits(): <exists T>Fruits<T> meaning it's a Fruits<T> for some T you don't know about. But that's not part of the language; there are workarounds, none are painless (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896593/2887218). How should we proceed with this question as written?

To clarify, I know most of the structure. I know that every category of fruit will have a contents property, and I know that every item in contents will have the associations record, where every key will be a valid category of fruit, and every value will be an array of items within that category, I just don't know what the specific categories will be, and I don't know what the specific items for each category will be.

Even if two items have the same identifier within their respective categories, they are still different and should not be mixed up (ie apple within alfa would be different to apple within bravo). As such, my main goal is to prevent mixing identifiers from different categories.

I'm really not sure how these last two comments moves us forward. If your question as asked, with its example, doesn't suffice to represent your needs, then you should [edit] to fix it, with a proper [mre] that demonstrates what you're saying here. Or is my suggested approach something that works for this question and you want to write a followup question post to dive more deeply into it? I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I am not sure if your suggested approach works yet - I'm trying to integrate it with a slightly more complex example to test whether it works nicely when the keys are not known, but I am just struggling to wrap my head around it well enough to work with it effectively (this is on me not you). I'll get back to you (probably tomorrow) once I've managed to try out your solution. Thanks so much for your help -- even if it doesn't turn out to meet my needs, your code is very helpful for learning the more advanced aspects of TypeScript's type system.
